# Using Chronicle Map producing garbage while using Streams API

Tags: java, stream, garbage-collection, chronicle, chronicle-map

Today I was experimenting with Chronicle Map. Here is a code sample:

```
package experimental;

import net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.IntValue;
import net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMap;
import net.openhft.chronicle.values.Values;

public class Tmp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (ChronicleMap<IntValue, User> users = ChronicleMap
                .of(IntValue.class, User.class)
                .name("users")
                .entries(100_000_000)
                .create();) {

            User user = Values.newHeapInstance(User.class);
            IntValue id = Values.newHeapInstance(IntValue.class);

            for (int i = 1; i < 100_000_000; i++) {

                user.setId(i);
                user.setBalance(Math.random() * 1_000_000);

                id.setValue(i);
                users.put(id, user);

                if (i % 100 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i + ". " +
                            users.values()
                                    .stream()
                                    .max(User::compareTo)
                                    .map(User::getBalance)
                                    .get());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface User extends Comparable<User> {

        int getId();
        void setId(int id);
        double getBalance();
        void setBalance(double balance);

        @Override
        default int compareTo(User other) {
            return Double.compare(getBalance(), other.getBalance());
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in above code I am just creating User object and putting it in Chronicle Map, and after each 100th record I am just printing the User with max balance. But unfortunately it is producing some garbage. When I monitored it with VisualVM I got the following:

[image: VisualVM Screenshot]

It seems using streams in Chronicle Map will produce garbage anyway.

So my questions are:
 * Does this mean that I should not use Streams API with Chronicle Map.
 * Are there any other solutions/ways of doing this?
 * How to filter/search Chronicle Map in proper way because I have use cases other than
just putting/getting data in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ChronicleMap`'s `entrySet().iterator()` (as well as iterator on `keySet()` and `values()`) is implemented so that it dumps all objects in a Chronicle Map's *segment* into memory before iterating over them.

You can inspect how much segments do you have by calling `map.segments()`. You could also configure it during the ChronicleMap construction phase, check out [ChronicleMapBuilder javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft/chronicle-map/3.17.8/net/openhft/chronicle/map/ChronicleMapBuilder.html).

So, during iteration, you should expect regularly, approximately `numEntries / numSegments` entries to be dumped into memory *at once*, where numEntries is the size of your Chronicle Map.

You can implement streaming processing on a Chronicle Map avoiding creating a lot of garbage, by reusing objects, via Segment Context API:

```
    User[] maxUser = new User[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < users.segments(); i++) {
        try (MapSegmentContext<IntValue, User, ?> c = map.segmentContext(i)) {
            c.forEachSegmentEntry((MapEntry<IntValue, User> e) -> {
              User user = e.value().get();
              if (maxUser[0] == null || user.compareTo(maxUser[0]) > 0) {
                // Note that you cannot just assign `maxUser[0] = user`:
                // this object will be reused by the SegmentContext later
                // in the iteration, and it's contents will be rewritten.
                // Check out the doc for Data.get().
                if (maxUser[0] == null) {
                  maxUser[0] = Values.newHeapInstance(User.class);
                }
                User newMaxUser = e.value().getUsing(maxUser[0]);
                // assert the object is indeed reused
                assert newMaxUser == maxUser[0];
              }
            });
        }
    }
```

Link to doc for [`Data.get()`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.openhft/chronicle-map/3.17.8/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/Data.html#get--).

The code of the above example is adapted from [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/502c6b701d23ce19e51310621923200a1c8802a9/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/map/MapDiagnostics.java#L35-L42).

Comment: I modified my code according to your code snippet, and it is creating too many object of `CompiledMapIterationContext$$Lambda$$`, but GC is not being called, even heap size is growing though.

Comment: It called GC after 18 minutes anyway.

Comment: This should be a defect, feel free to submit it at https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/issues

Comment: Is it possible that the line `User user = e.value().get();` producing garbage? I just solved this by `double max =-1; max = Math.max(max, e.value().getUsing(maxUser[0]).getBalance()); return max;`, i.e. getting max balance as a double;

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but nevertheless it should be considered a defect.